# How to get view when calling a method with data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, onclick, android-databinding

I'm calling a method from onClick attribute with databinding on an ImageView :

```
android:onClick="@{() -> myClass.myMethod()}"
```

myMethod() gets a view as parameter i know i can do something like this :

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> myClass.myMethod(view)}"
```

but i want to pass ImageView not View

any suggestions on this ?

Comment: view is generic type so u have to cast it to imageview (ImageView)view where u want in method if u setting onclick to ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast.

Or you can pass view object directly. DataBinding generates view accessors to views by view id (for example if your ImageView has id `user_picture`, you can access to it from DataBinding layout as `userPicture`).

But I don't recommend to do that, better to create custom BindingAdapter, because your view model in most cases shouldn't access to views or context directly, but all view-specific things should be processed in BindingAdapters.